Every integral curve that intersects $S$ is contained in $S$. Why does $S$ have to be properly embdedded?
I am trying to show the following
Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, $S \subseteq M$ is an immersed submanifold, and $V$ is a smooth vector field on $M$ that is tangent to $S$.
Assume that $S$ is properly embedded. Show that every integral curve that intersects $S$ is contained in $S$.

Here is the proof I came up with for this theorem:
Fix an integral curve $\gamma(t)$ which intersects $S$ at some point $\gamma(t_0)$. Then consider the restriction of the vector field to $S$ called $\left.V\right|_S$. Then there is a unique maximal integral curve of the restricted vector field contained in $S$ which equals the original curve starting at $\gamma(t_0)$. By uniquness of integral curves, the original curve after time $t_0$ lies in $S$.
Now consider the curve in reverse. By the same argument, the time reversed curve is also contained in $S$. Thus, the entire curve must have been in $S$.
However I didn't use that $S$ was properly embdedded. Where was this required in my argument?

"Then there is a unique maximal integral curve of the restricted vector field contained in $S$" Sure, but you have not shown that this equals the maximal integral curve $\gamma$ in $M$. In fact, if you assume for convenience that $\gamma$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, then the restriction to $S$ need not be. Think about the case $M = \mathbb{R}$, $S = (0, 1)$ with integral curve $\mathrm{id}\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, for example.

@BenSteffan Would this example you gave fail because $S$ is not closed?

...because $S$ is not closed and therefore not properly embedded.

@BenSteffan I think my issue is that I don't quite understand the notion of being properly embedded. My understanding is that an embedding $F:M\to N$ is a smooth surjection which is a homeomorphic with image, and proper meaning $F(N) \subsetneq M$. Is this correct?

Ah, "proper" is a term of art here: a (continuous) map is proper if preimages of compact sets under it are compact. But really, what one should memorize is what's proposition 5.5 in Lee: An embedded submanifold is properly embedded iff it is closed.

@BenSteffan Ah thanks so much for clearing that up. Should I instead considered $S=[0,1]$ would we then get that the curve alway stays in $[0,1]$? Is $[0,1]$ an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}$?

$[0, 1]$ won't work, because it's a manifold with boundary, and this result does not hold for manifolds with boundary (in fact, replacing $(0, 1)$ with $[0, 1]$ here doesn't change anything). You might want to try $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. (Also, I think you got your notions slightly confused there: An embedding $F\colon M \to N$ is a smooth map that is a diffeomorphism onto its image, which is the same as saying it's a smooth homeomorphism).

Hmm ok I see, so the only properly embedded submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}$ would be $\mathbb{R}$ itself?

Don't forget about dimension 0! Any finite number of points in $\mathbb{R}$ form an embedded 0-manifold, and the same is true for a countably infinite set of "nicely separated" points. But yes, otherwise there's only the identity.

@BenSteffan Can I think of these definitions as essentially injective <-> immersion, surjection <-> submersion, bijection <-> embedding? So an embedding is both an immersion and a submersion? Then a proper embedding is like a more specific kind of embedding

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
